# scanf() and integer array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm trying to make a simple program which outputs the maximum value and minimum value from the user's input.

But it always takes one more input than I intend.

It seems to have a problem with `scanf()` but I'm not really sure.

```
int num, max = -100000, min = 1000000;

scanf("%d", &num);

int array[num];

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    scanf("%d ", &array[i]);
    if (max < array[i])
        max = array[i];

    if (min > array[i])
        min = array[i];
}

printf("%d %d", max, min);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing space in the format string `scanf("%d ", &array[i]);` causes `scanf()` to consume all newlines until you type something non blank, which you interpret as requiring an extra input. Remove this trailing space.

Also test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input.

Furthermore, you do not need to store the values into an array.

Also note that `-100000` and `1000000` are not safe initial values: what if all values typed by the user are below or above these thresholds? Use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` or test the index value.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, num, val, max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX;

    if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (scanf("%d ", &val) != 1) {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                break;
            }
            if (val < min)
                min = val;
            if (val > max)
                max = val;
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("no values\n");
        } else {
            printf("%d %d\n", max, min);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```